# How to tell Dagger2 to create a new instance of an object in the same class?

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I have this `ViewModel` class:

```
public class BarsViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private BarsSourceFactory factory;

    @Inject
    BarsViewModel(BarsSourceFactory factory) {
        this.factory = factory;
        Log.d(TAG, "factory: " + factory.toString());  //Same address in memory
    }

    void replace() {
        //Use factory object to create some stuff
        Log.d(TAG, "factory: " + factory.toString()); //Same address in memory
    }
}
```

Both log statements print the same address in memory. How to tell Dagger2 in `replace()` method to create a new object of `BarsSourceFactory` class?

Comment: you can't. If you describe what you want to achieve maybe we can help you find a different solution

Comment: @Blackbelt Thanks for your comment. That `factory` object is used for a pagination algorithm and I want to create a new object so different results will be returned. Since it is the same object, the same results are returned. Any idea?

Comment: expose a function in your factory that does some data resetting ?

Comment: @Blackbelt Yes, that's right, `replace()` method does that. In order to create a search, it removes the observer and add it again. It replaces the subscription. That's why I need a different object and not the same one.

Comment: @Blackbelt I have also tried to add in my `AppModule` class, `@Provides
    static BarsSourceFactory provideBarsSourceFactory(BarsDataSource barsDataSource) {
        return new BarsSourceFactory(barsDataSource);
    }` and the result is the same. Same address for both objects.

Comment: I don't think you can do it with dagger

Comment: @Blackbelt In that case, I'll go the traditional way of passing objects to the constructor. Thank you so much for that.

Comment: Why should `factory` ever change? If you assign the field in the constructor, and never change it, it will always be the same value/object. If you want to create new objects you can have a look at (sub)component builders / factories and / or `Provider<T>`, which can both create "new" objects on demand

Comment: @DavidMedenjak Thanks David, I'll definitely take a look at that.